# VBA File name reference issue- file explorer view file extension

Tags: vba, microsoft-file-explorer

We have a template we use to generate a proposal using a a couple of different excel files and word templates. I just spent the last couple of days trying to figure out why the code stopped working for me even though there was no change and my coworker's was working fine. Then after finding a somewhat similar problem and someone pointed to the file explorer settings when it hit me that I had changed the explorer view to show file extensions (occasionally need to do this). Of course, disabling the extension view fixed the issue.

is there any work around to this? Or maybe a better way to structure our code to avoid this problem?

Any advice on the best way to avoid this issue for other users in the future would be much appreciated.

Comment: How was the code not working for you?

Comment: Fix your code so it always uses the full file name (with extension) when referring to files.  That will work regardless of the Windows Explorer "hide file extensions" setting.